# what is response.write in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, response.write

This will be quite simple but

What is the best way of using classical webforms "response.write" in asp net MVC. Especially mvc5.

Let's say: I just would like to write a simple string to screen from controller.

Does response.write exist in mvc?

Thanks.

Comment: you can return a plain string from a controller-action

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the return type of your method is an `ActionResult`, You can use the `Content` method to return any type of content.

```
public ActionResult MyCustomString()
{
   return Content("YourStringHere");
}
```

or simply

```
public String MyCustomString()
{
  return "YourStringHere";
}
```

[Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.content(v=vs.118).aspx) method allows you return other content type as well, Just pass the content type as second param.

```
 return Content("<root>Item</root>","application/xml");
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Shyju said you should use `Content` method, But there's another way by creating a custom action result, Your custom action-result could look like this::

```
public class MyActionResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly string _content;

    public MyActionResult(string content)
    {
        _content = content;
    }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(_content);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it, this way:

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return new MyActionResult("content");
    }
```