# how to print text on web console with asp.net core c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

with asp.net framework, I have used Response.Write("string here") to display data from controller on console of web browser app. But how do we do that in .net core?

I have tried

```
HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(Response,"string here");
```

But it shows a network connection error.
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You mean the dev tools (F12) console tab?  `Response.Write` just writes to the response stream going to the browser (eg the html content), not the console specifically. Am I misunderstanding?  The dev tools console is for Javascript messages, eg. `console.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI `Response.Write` is removed from `MVC`.

There are two Solutions for `.Net Core MVC` is by using `Content Result` or by writing your custom `ActionResult` by overriding `ExecuteResult` method as below.

**1. Using Content Result**

```
 public IActionResult Index()
 {

  return Content("Hello World !");
 }
```

or even Just return `string` method

```
public string Index()
{
  return "Hello World !";
}
```

**2. Custom Action Result:**

```
 public class ResponseWriteActionResult : ActionResult
 {
      public override void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
      {
          var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World !");

          context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(str, 0, str.Length);
      }

 }
```

**Usage:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{

   return new ResponseWriteActionResult();
}
```

References:

[1.](https://forums.asp.net/t/1434248.aspx?Is+there+an+equivalent+of+response+write+in+asp+net+mvc+)

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072742/2218697)

[3.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33847845/2218697)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use

```
Console.WriteLine("Any String");
```