# Response.Write method not working on .net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Response.Write("String Goes here.");

Above statement showing an error inside my .net core 2.1 project's controller .Even if i have included the references like 
System.web .

Exact Error msg:

Error   CS1061  'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no accessible extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thank you

Comment: Without the error it's hard to help. I'm assuming this is an MVC application where Response.Write does not exist, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847767/what-is-response-write-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Im using .net mvc core 2.1

Comment: I'm getting error msg : Error CS1061 'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no accessible extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: As I said, MVC doesn't have Response.Write (like the old Asp.net Forms did), you need to use another approach, see the link in my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http Nuget Package and namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http then you can use :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http ;
....
Response.Write("String Goes here.");
```

Comment: change Response.Write to Response.WriteAsync if it does not work